# how can i remove the status bar (with time, battery)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, interface-builder, statusbar

i want to remove the status bar (where the time and the battery status is displayed). like in doodle jump or other games.
how can I do this?

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2008/06/hide-status-bar.html
there you go mate.

Comment: that link is almost longer than the solution.

Comment: lol, but the link can lead to the answers of other questions too.

Comment: works, but it's deprecated. i found out: [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
Thank you :)

Comment: Well that's interesting, sorry for the depreciation. Glad you found the correct solution!

Comment: For iOS 7, see this SO question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7