# Pull twice to show notification center or control panel?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Recently, I am trying to fix issues of my app after release of iOS7.
One of the most annoying problem is about the pull-up control panel: since my app has pull up menu, apparently, the pull-up gesture triggers control panel simultaneously.

However, I found some apps are not affecting by this issue cause they need to **pull twice** to show the control panel, such as Slideshark. When user perform a pull-up gesture, the menu shows up with a "pull up tab" at the bottom of the screen(see **red rectangle**).

[image: Slideshark]

So the user need to pull up again to trigger the control panel.
I do not think pull-up menu is a good idea in iOS7, but this seems temporarily fix the problem. Anyone know how to do this?

Hubert

Comment: This should be controlled by whether the status bar is visible in your app. If the status bar is hidden, you should get this behavior automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get this behavior automatically when you hide the status bar in your app.

This question explains ways to hide the status bar on iOS 7: [Cannot hide status bar in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

(You can do it on a per view controller basis, or for your entire app at once.)