# Hide status bar in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I need to hide the status-bar on iOS7. I already tried to set:

```
Status bar is initially hidden
```

and

```
View controller-based status bar appearance
```

into the plist file. Status-bar doesn't appears when app in launched, but when I change view-controller (is a tabbed app) status-bar appears!

I already tried to set

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

in a view-controller, but doesn't works. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance :)

**UPDATE**

I partially resolve the issue by setting "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "YES" into info.plist and calling the method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

into the view-controller. But now I got another problem: status-bar appears when I launch another controller (UIImagePickerController). I tried to set `[myPicker prefersStatusBarHidden];` but it seems to be read-only. Anyone know the solution?

P.S.: `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO` and `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO` are the same thing..

Comment: Correct solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21034908/294884

Answer (score 7):

add this key to your info.plist

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO
```

Answer (score 3):

Set

```
UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = YES
```

in the info.plist and in each controller implement

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES; // or NO
}
```

Then whenever you need a status bar appearance update (e.g. in the `viewDidLoad` of a controller) call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`.

As per the documentation of [`setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate):

> Call this method if the view controller's status bar attributes, such as hidden/unhidden status or style, change. If you call this method within an animation block, the changes are animated along with the rest of the animation block.

So for instance

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

    ...
}
```

will hide/unhide the status bar (aside from other potential style changes) whenever the view controller's view loads.

Optionally you can also animate the transition wrapping the call in an animation block

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }]; 

    ...
}
```