# iOS7 Hiding the status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, statusbar

I've tried everything I can think of/find to hide the status bar on iOS 7, but after the launch it appears:

```
//in viewDidLoad
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

//in the main view controller
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

I also set "Status bar is initially hidden", and "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES in the info.plist.

Oddly, the status bar does hide after another controller appears, like a picker or the keyboard.

Comment: Is your VC hosted by a container view controller?

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a new value to your info.plist:

> View Controller based status bar appearance - NO

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want view controllers to participate in the style and visibility of the status bar, add a "View Controller based status bar appearance" row to your `info.plist` and set it to `NO`. By default, in iOS 7, view controllers can participate in the status bar appearance process by overriding the `prefersStatusBarHidden` method. You could also notify UIKit about your status bar visibility change by calling `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]`.

If it's still not working, post a little bit more code to see a bigger picture of your problem. Maybe the cause is somewhere else.