# Problems with automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets, status bar and keyboard

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview, keyboard, statusbar

I get a `UIScrollView` which shows an offset of its content below the status bar. I've read some posts regarding that issue, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816799/ios7-uiscrollview-show-offset-content-below-status-bar), and I actually get rid of the status bar offset by setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller.

But this scroll view contains several text fields I need to scroll when the keyboard is shown and hides them, and having `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` set to `NO`, prevents the scrolling when the keyboard is shown. I tried to set it to `YES` again in the `keyboardWasShown:` callback, but it has no effect.

I really need help with this issue, how could I solve it?

Thanks in advance