# statusBarHidden:YES; But the empty/ clear space is still there?

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar, uistatusbar

I have hidden the status bar in my app by using:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`

But for some reason when the view is initially loaded, I get the view with the disabled status bar, but the space for the bar is still there, see the following for reference:
[image]

But when I rotate the device, I get the normal behavior:

[image]

And if I was to rotate my device back to the portrait view again, everything would look normal and that gap will no longer be there, its only present initially.

Why I'm I having this issue? **Please provide as many details as possible**

**UPDATE:** I have deleted all of my

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`
 to follow the solution that was provided here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7?lq=1) but unfortunately this is giving me the same result as I posted above.

Comment: When do you call `setStatusBarHidden`? Have you tried changing your app's plist file instead, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)?

Comment: @godel9 it took me a few minutes to respond, as I went thru my code and removed the `setStatusBarHidden` and simply added the .plist instructions but this still gives me the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

in view controller add this method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden 
{
    return YES;
}
```