# CardIOPaymentViewController hiding status bar

Tags: ios, card.io

I'm having trouble hiding the status bar with my CardIOPaymentViewController. None of my other views display the status bar. I'm using the Card.io SDK in iOS7 and it presents fine modally - just that the status bar is always shown with this view. My info.plist has:

```
Status bar is initially hidden = YES
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

and I've checked the **Hide During Application Launch** option in the Deployment Info Section.

I've tried:

```
self.keepStatusBarStyle = YES;
```

I've also made sure my CardIOPaymentViewController controller has (which I didn't need for my other view controllers):

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Any suggestions or similar experiences?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot hide status bar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

Comment: I've previously seen and tried everything in that post. None of them worked. Bear in mind, I have the status bar hidden in all my other views, just not the one with the Card.io sdk view controller.

Comment: Dave from card.io here. @rizjoj does this only happen if you're running on a 4" device (or simulator), and not a 3.5" one? If so, then I think it may be an easily fixable bug in our SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DaveGoldman. I'm doing this on a 4" device. I do have a 3.5" device which I will try and let you know the results.

Answer (score 2):

@rizjoj I believe that I have now identified and fixed the problem -- the CardIOPaymentViewController wasn't respecting the "View controller-based status bar appearance" setting.

But before I post an official update, I'd like to send you the updated SDK to test. My email address is in my profile; could you get in touch?

Comment: thanks and sorry for the delayed response. It took me some time to dig out my old iPhone device and provision it. I wanted to verify this on the device in addition to the simulator. I've just verified, as you've discovered by now, that the status bar remains displayed on both the simulator and devices for 3.5" and 4" screens. I'd be happy to get in touch with you via email. Expect a message from me in your inbox. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dave, this is happening to me on the latest version. The status bar always gets hidden just before the cardio view controller is presented. I cannot stop it.. Any ideas?