# Hide statusbar using info.plist in any app

Tags: ios, ios7, info.plist

To clarify, I'm not trying to do this on my own app, so I don't have access to the source code. I am trying to edit info.plist or any other files in the installed .app file on my device to remove the status bar from an app, namely Google Chrome

I'm trying to hide the statusbar on Google Chrome. I added `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = false` and `UIStatusBarHidden = true` to `info.plist`, but all that got me was a grey bar where the status bar used to be. So close!

Are there any other ways to force hide the status bar in Chrome or any other app on iOS 7?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7

Comment: This is common question now a Days you have to do some google or RND regarding this issue.

Answer (score 7):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
```

OR

[image]

Or

try
`- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden { return YES; }` in all of your view controllers.

Comment: I don't have access to the headers or any of the source, trying to do this on Google Chrome app

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

`add this key into info.plist file`

View controller-based status bar appearance

`set value for this to:- No`

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance set to no? I've already got that in the info.plist

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned in my first post

Comment: then u have to hide it programatically.

Answer (score 5):

I added the following to my info.plist:

`Status bar is initially hidden` with value `YES`

I also have `View controller-based status bar appearance` with value `NO`

[image: Screenshot showing info.plist properties]