# How to hide StatusBar in the course of launching,and show it again after the launching

Tags: ios, statusbar

Could anyone tell me how to hide StatusBar in the course of launching and show it again after the launching?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965610/hide-the-status-bar-in-ios-9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147706/how-to-hide-status-bar-when-splash-screen-appears-in-iphone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865639/hide-statusbar-using-info-plist-in-any-app duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple, set `Status bar is initially hidden YES` in Info.plist file and also Make sure your not set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIStatusBarHidden to true or false in the info.plist in order to show or hide the status bar when launching.

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 0):

set this in your info plist file.[image]