# iOS7 how to completely hide status bar throughout app?

Tags: ios7, statusbar, sprite-kit, uistatusbar

I'm building a sprite kit game, and normally status bar does not show within my app. However, the drag and drop code that I'm using is doing something with the window and when the item is being dragged, the status bar flickers on and off. So my question is:

**How can I completely and utterly tell iOS7 to hide status bar everywhere within my app?**

I tried plugging per controller code, but cannot seem to find which particular controller is showing the status bar.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

I have status bar set to initially hidden in plist:
[image]

I tried using `setStatusBarHidden` within `appDidFinishLaunching`

Maybe there's some centralized setting I can set to off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot hide status bar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setStatusBarHidden` setting and the "Status bar is initially hidden" Info.plist setting do not work unless you also set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" Info.plist key (`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`) to "NO".

In other words, either you're doing this at the level of every single top-level view controller or you're doing it at the global UIApplication level, and this key determines which it is.

However, it is better to learn to do it the view controller way, because Apple might eventually take away the option to do it at the global UIApplication level.