# iOS 7 Status Bar won't go away despite everything set to hide it

Tags: ios7, plist, xcode5, ios7-statusbar

I've been having an issue with most of the apps I've been working on where in iOS7 I cannot get the status bar to disappear. It's all perfectly fine for iOS 6.1 and below but nothing I was doing was making it go away.

My settings in my Plist look like this:

`UIStatusBarHidden => YES`
`UIStatusBarHidden~ipad => YES`

In my Xib files I've made sure that my views have **Status Bar** set to *None* (see screenshot) yet despite both of these set the glorious iOS7 status bar keeps appearing.

[image: Simulated metrics in Xcode showing status bar setting is none]

I then thought that maybe I had to set the **Status Bar Style** in the General target settings to *Hide during application launch* (see screenshot) but this too had no effect.

[image: Deployment info settings under General tab in Xcode]

I have spent hours trying to get this one right!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot hide status bar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is actually very simple. There is a setting you need to add to your project plist file called **View controller-based status bar appearance** which needs to be set to *NO*.

[image: View controller setting for the plist file]

The key pair is as follows:

`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` => `NO`

In the end your plist should look like this:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```