# IOS7 upgrade - Status bar not hiding on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios6, ios7, upgrade, ios7-statusbar

Hi I'm upgrading my Universal app from iOS6 to iOS7.
I'm hiding the status bar by using this inside .plist file:

```
-> Status bar is initially hidden = YES
-> View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

Then inside my AppDelegate *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* I added:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                   withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

**The statusbar is correctly hidden when running on:**

- IOS6 [iPhone,iPad]
- IOS7 [iPhone]

I only have issues on iPad/iOs7. I can't hide it here!

Any Help?

Comment: Hi Did u manage to find a solution? I tried all the answers in here and still not working for iPAD only. Or is this a bug of the iOS?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your xcode project is not target only for iphone.

in my case, my xcode project is target only for iphone, and i'm building my project in ipad with 2x zoom
so non of hide statusBar solution worked for me.
here is my Solution, i just change Device type to ipad under Deployment info column. and apply this

```
Status bar is initially hidden = YES
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

into info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.openfl.org/community/general-discussion/iphone-5ios-7-cant-hide-status-bar/

I found it from this post [Cannot hide status bar in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

you can still hide the status bar, but it's up to each view controller subclass in your app to override: prefersStatusBarHidden to return YES