# Set statusbar to hidden in C4

Tags: statusbar, c4

Since iOS7 I have had a hard time hiding the status bar in apps. I've tried most of the tricks in [another thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7) and I am still unable to hide the status bar. How might I do this in C4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7), there's a trick listed as one of the answers that states:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

You'll want to add this to your workspace.