# Getting rid of the ios status bar in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

I have a tab bar that calls a `UIImagePickerController` like so:

```
    UIImagePickerController *photo = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    photo.delegate = self;
    photo.allowsEditing = NO;
    photo.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    [self presentViewController:photo animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But the status bar remains even witht the `setStatusBarHidden` to `YES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your plist file in Xcode and this key to no

view controller-based status bar appearance' and set to NO., that did the trick for me

Comment: Yes true but not for the UIImagePicker, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7

Answer (score 0):

Try by implementing the following delegate method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through following code

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

   if([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]&& ((UIImagePickerController*)navigationController).sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
   {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: how does this get called?

Comment: so it performs the code on behalf of the delegate object (uinavigationcontroller) but I still see a status bar in my uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7