# Obj-C, random hide status bar with "prefersStatusBarHidden"

Tags: objective-c

I trying to hide the status bar when click on image.
I am calling the BOOL Method when click on image by:

```
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
```

and here the method:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    NSLog(@"%@",hideBar);
    if ([hideBar isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        NSLog(@"hide");
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

when I click on the image I get the "NSLog("hide")", that mean that the "if statement" is work but the status bar doesn't get hide, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are not supposed to call the `prefersStatusBarHidden` method directly. It will be called as needed by the system.

Comment: I know but I am trying to hide the status bar when I open image full size, in what other way can I perform it?

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIApplication`. There are methods for changing the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)
just add in my app's plist file a row - "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to NO

and hide the status bar with:

```
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```