# Nevigation bar is black when execute code

Tags: ios

i have implemented code in which when i press button UIView Contains datepicker come from bottom and displayed

but it make navigation bar black 
and when i press on hide button it make navigation bar normal 
navigation bar contains just title

i have uiscroll view before UIView contains date picker

```
- (void)datePickerShow
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect location = [self.view1 frame];
        location.origin.y =[self.scrollViewProfile frame].size.height - location.size.height;
        NSLog(@"%f",location.origin.y);
        [self.view1 setFrame:location];
        //  [self.scrollViewProfile setContentOffset:(CGPointMake(0,location.size.height) ) animated:YES];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void) datePickerHide
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect location = [self.view1 frame];
        location.origin.y =[self.scrollViewProfile frame].size.height +location.size.height;
        NSLog(@"%f",[self.scrollViewProfile frame].size.height);
        [self.view1 setFrame:location];
        [self.scrollViewProfile setContentOffset:(CGPointMake(0,0))animated:true];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Comment: Can you paste code, please?

Comment: view1 contains UIDatepicker control

Comment: Need more information. Information about hierarchy of views/controllers

Comment: what you exactly want to show

UIView 
   -UIScrollView

Comment: @alex_izh Hierarchy is  **UIView**  contains two subviews **UIScrollView**
and **View1**  , **UIScrollView**  Contains all basic controls like button and label etc , and **View1** it is view which contains **UIDatepicker control**

Comment: Does view1 in the separate View Controller?

Comment: It could not happen because UIDatePicker. You have another problem, but we can't find it, because you provide a little information

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable View Controller-based status bar appearance. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18549998/3429577

Comment: I don't want to disable status bar there .

Comment: I don't suggest you to do it. View Controller can affect status bar style.