# prefersStatusBarHidden not called

Tags: ios, statusbar

I have a `UITabViewController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UIViewController` and want to hide and unhide the statusBar. when I call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` the method `prefersStatusBarHidden` is not called.

```
func fadeOutStatusBar (notification: NSNotification) {
    statusBarHidden = true
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

func fadeInStatusBar (notification: NSNotification) {
    statusBarHidden = false
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}
```

Comment: This has discussed in so many times in OS. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

Comment: only the accepted answer is the opposite to mine

Comment: @Md1079, that is because your question was not very clear - it sounded like you were asking how to do that in just one view, so most people gave you solutions to just tweak one view, while Nghia Luong responded with both options that could help.

Comment: You might want to check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714171/iphonex-not-call-prefersstatusbarhidden/52210933#52210933

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured it out. in info.plist file:
 view controller-status bar appearance should be set to YES

Comment: Your answer here would be more useful if you explained in more detail what this will achieve  Local status bar hiding? Globally across the app?   (FYI your answer shows how to do it globally - while your initial question seems to ask how to do it for 'a view')  This is confusing and unclear. I think you should accept Nghia's answer for this question.

Comment: Yes, it let the viewcontrollers handle the status bar. Otherwise, the delegate is never called.

Answer (score 40):

Firstly, `View controller-based status bar appearance` in the `.plist` file must be set to **YES**.

- If you want status bar to be hidden in the **whole** app:

**For Objective-C:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

**For Swift:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarHidden = true

    return true
}
```

- If you want status bar is disappeared in **Specify View Controller**, in `.m` file, just implement:

**For Objective-C:**

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

**For Swift:**

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: For Swift 3: `application.setStatusBarHidden(true, with: .none)`

and

`override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
  return true
 }`

Comment: I forgot about the plist, Thanks!

Comment: You also need to set `Status bar is initially hidden` to YES

Comment: `statusBarHidden` has been renamed to `isStatusBarHidden`

Answer (score 16):

For swift 3, first, make sure that `View controller-based status bar appearance` is set to `YES` in your `Info` plist file

[image: screenshot]

And then just add this to your view controller:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

I hope this helps people in the future.

Answer (score 12):

When we nested the **UINavigationController**, our
**AppDelegate. Window. RootViewController**
Usually we create navigationController when first will call in the navigationController **childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden** function, because the default returns nil, then is called navigationController **prefersStatusBarHidden** function itself, So the status bar that we set in viewController through the **prefersStatusBarHidden** function will not be called, so it won't work.
So we're going to create our own one that inherits from the **NavigationController**,in this subclass **ChildViewControllerForStatusBarHidden** function.

If you are using a `UINavigationController` as your `window.rootViewController` from your `AppDelegate`, then you might want to extend `UINavigationController` in order to call its `topViewController`'s `prefersStatusBarHidden`:

```
class YourNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Just saved me from hitting my head against the wall! Thanks!!

Comment: Me too. I was going crazy. Nobody has mentioned this. Thanks @JackySong

Comment: Same here on Swift 5. Tried everything else, and this was what finally did it. If your app subclasses UINavigationController make sure you try this + overriding `prefersStatusBarHidden` in your ViewController.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe not a solution to the OP problem, but what could also be the cause for `prefersStatusBarHidden` not being called is if you have used a second window in your app delegate, eg for displaying a splash screen, and you did not hide it after the splash was shown - then that window gets the events that lead to calling these functions.

Comment: Thank you for this. How did you end up fixing this situation so that the status bar is shown?

Comment: I don't remember - but probably hide the window I mentioned :-)

Answer (score 2):

Property `prefersStatusBarHidden` is being called on the root view controller of the current view controller.

This means that if your app is based on a `UISplitViewController` for example, you must implement the property in a custom `UISplitViewController` class.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4.2 iOS 12

Assuming you have a `ViewController` contained within `UINavigationController`. Create your own Subclass of `UINavigationController` and include in it:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Make sure `info.plist` sets `View Controller` based setting of status bar

Answer (score 1):

If you have other `window` not hidden, the method not be called. Just hide other window, it will work as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You just simply need to hide the navigation controller and the `statusBar` will also hidden.

try this `viewDidLoad` example

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```