# Swift 2 prefersStatusBarHidden() Not Called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm in the same situation as [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541525/prefersstatusbarhidden-not-called). For some reason, the status bar still doesn't fade in or out. I've pretty much tried every solution posted on this website.

I'm using a `UINavigationController` -> `UIViewController`.

I have `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES`.
Here's my code:

```
var statusBarHidden = false

func toggleStatusBarHidden() {
    statusBarHidden = !statusBarHidden
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() {
    return statusBarHidden
}

override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() {
    return .Fade
}
```

Any ideas why that might be the case?

Comment: Are you by any chance targeting iOS 10? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38902285/1166266

Comment: Nope. I do know that Swift 3 uses `var` instead of `func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my problem. I created the function on a view controller bounded by a UIContainerView. I need to move those methods into the parent view controller.

Comment: Right. Only the _root view controller_ is consulted.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as well. I ended up using the following method in `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDissapear`:

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
```

Note: It's deprecated in iOS 9.0, but still usable.