# iphoneX not call prefersStatusBarHidden

Tags: swift, iphone-x, uistatusbar

info.plist

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
```

UIViewController

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
   }
```

when i use 6p ,it's ok
but
iphoneX ,it's can't call and StatusBar not hidden

Comment: UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = true

Comment: please increase the understandability of your question

Comment: override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{ return true } can't be call in iphoneX

Comment: same problem here, please post a solution if you find it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check if your view controller is included in a container (i.e. *UINavigationController*). If that is the case, the full procedure is this:

1) Set the View `controller-based status bar appearance` value in **info.plist** file to YES

2) In your child controller add this code:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return true
   }
```

3) Add this extension:

```
// gives control of the status bar appearance to the top controller
extension UINavigationController {
    override open var childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return self.topViewController
    }
}
```

You already have point 1 and 2. Same logic applies to UITabBarController