# prefersStatusBarHidden issue in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

Hi everyone I'm trying to hide my **statusBar** in a `View Controller` but it doesn't seem to work .. I used the function:

---

```
 override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
         return true
    }
```

---

I also set the **`View controller-based status bar appearance`** in the `plist` file to **YES**

My status bar doesn't want to hide ... where am I doing wrong?

Comment: `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` under `Info.plist`. You can check your settings for status bar [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK9c2.png)

Comment: try this : `(UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as? UIWindow)?.isHidden = false`

Comment: crash with this error UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'

Comment: @kAiN did you check my answer? I've tested right now with empty project with `Status bar is initially hidden` as `YES` and `View controller-based status bar appearance` as `NO` in `plist` without adding any code - the status bar is hidden on iOS13.3 and iPhone11

Comment: @VadimNikolaev Yes, I know that, but I need my status bar not only visible in a specific view controller

Comment: @kAiN please check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52210933/5928311). I guess it'll useful for your case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to specifically hide the status bar in a single `ViewController`.

In order to do that, you need have the following in that `ViewController`

`self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true`

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
      return true
}
```

I also added `View controller-based status bar appearance` in my `.plist` and set it to `YES`.

Tested on the latest iOS 13.

Comment: It works for me. But on iOS 14, I do not need to set `self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true` , it also works well.

Answer (score 0):

If the target view controller is embedded in another container view controller such as `UINavigationController` you need to subclass that container view controller and override its `childForStatusBarHidden` to return the target view controller.

Answer (score 0):

you kan look this，you should override  childForStatusBarHidden and  childForStatusBarStyle 。

```
class CCNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return self.topViewController
    }
    
    override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return self.topViewController
    }
}
```