# ModelPresentationStyle FullScreen hides always the StatusBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to open a new window in fullscreen but I don't want to get the StatusBar hidden.

The ViewControllers property `modalPresentationStyle` has the value `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` and the property `prefersStatusBarHidden` has the value `NO` (`false`);

But the StatusBar is already hidden. Any idea?

Comment: Why is the question voted negativ?

Comment: We have no way of knowing what you are doing, and no reason to believe you are doing it correctly. Please do not _describe_ your code. _Show_ your code.

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59733252/prefersstatusbarhidden-issue-in-ios-13 Do you are seeing a lot of code here? My question is a combination of properties and I am mentioning the properties and the values.What more do you want to see?

Comment: Well, that is why the question is voted negatively.

Comment: Ok, anyway thanks for the info. The code is not mine, is from a plugin and I am trying to change the code in order to work as expected.

Comment: But your question doesn't mention any plugin. Once again, I say: show your code. If you do not tell us what we need to know in order to help, we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the status bar is determined by the view controller that is being presented. If you override `prefersStatusBarHidden` on that view controller you should get your desired result.

Comment: and with modelPresentationStyle should I use? I have overriden the property and it have not effect

Comment: I added also `modalPresentationCaptureStatusBarAppearance` equals to `true` but it does not work